# How to get all the news of the selected tag in CoreData?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, predicate

I have two entities News and Tag.
News have to-many relationship to Tag and Tag has to-many relationship to News (inverse relationships).

```
Tag:
-tagcontent
News:
-title
-newscontent
```

How to get the list of all News with the tagcontent=@"Cars"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use somehting like this - **ANY** should help you

```
     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSString *tagName = @"Cars";
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"News" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tag.tagcontent = %@",tagName];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSrray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to update the fetchedResultsController with the new list of News

Comment: can you write a line of code how to feed NSSet to fetchedResultsController

Comment: An NSFetchedResultsController leverages a NSFetchRequest.  Just create the NSFetchResultsController using the NSFetchRequest that Nikita provided for you.

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController is already created. I need to update it with the new data. The data is stored in NSSet news. How to add the data to NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: Updated my answer,so you can use it in your fetchedresultscontroller